# Direct conversion from base 2 to base 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

Is there any way to convert a number that is represented in base 2 *directly* to base 3? Or do we need to always convert to base 10 first in order to get to base 3?

Comment: You can convert directly in the same way that you convert from base $10$.  Of course, most people aren't familiar with long division in other bases but there's nothing all that different about it.